# Can we find record that doesn't exist in table using mysql Procedure?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySql Procedure to update value, but before that I am checking if record exists. And condition is, if record exist then just update the detailand it is updating very well.

Now my question is **How to find records that doesn't exist in table and return that all value(which is not exist or doesn't satisfied IF EXISTS condition).** Below I am sharing my MySql Procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_ABC`(
IN `_startdate` DATE,
IN `_enddate` DATE,
IN `_invc` VARCHAR(100),
IN `_amt` VARCHAR(100),
IN `_stones` VARCHAR(100),
IN `_tracking` VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT invc, value, ttl_stones FROM tbl_quality WHERE invc = '_invc' AND value = 
     '_amt' AND ttl_stones = '_stones' AND DATE(date) BETWEEN '_startdate' AND '_enddate')

        THEN

            UPDATE quality_memo SET trackid = '_tracking'
            WHERE invc = '_invc' AND value = '_amt' AND ttl_stones = '_stones' AND 
                  DATE(date) BETWEEN '_startdate' AND '_enddate';
     ELSE   
         
         -- HERE I WANT TO FIND OR RETURN **invc, value, ttl_stones** WHICH ROW DIDN'T GOT UPDATED 
           -- or NOT FOUND or IF EXISTS CONDITION NOT GOT SATISFIED
        
    END IF;
    
 END
```

Also, I am sharing my PHP code, where I am using ARRAY and FOR-EACH LOOP to pass value in PROCEDURE.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
 include "config.php";

 $s = '';
 $trackingmyarray = $_POST['trackingmyarray'];

 $tracking = json_decode($trackingmyarray, true);

 if (is_array($tracking)) {
   foreach ($tracking as $item) {

    $s .= "CALL `sp_ABC`('".$item['startdate']."', '" . $item['enddate'] . "', 
                                '".$item['invc1']."', '".$item['amt']."', 
                                '".$item['stones']."', '".$item['tracking']."');";
     }
 }

$res = query($s);


if (strlen($res) > 0) {
      echo $res;
} else {
   echo 'Records added successfully...';
 }

 ?>
```

I hope I made my concern clear. Again in simple words, **if value doesn't satisfied IF EXISTS condtion then print it as output**

Any help will be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: can you use  insert on duplicate update?

Comment: @AnonyMouze, I cant insert if values not found, I just have to show, which value not found or doesn't exist. in table.

Comment: And again. If row exists it must be updated. But if row not exists it must be inserted? or not - report only?

Comment: @Akina, AKINA No INSERTION needed here just report. I want if row not exists then just print that row as output. I hope I am bit clear now. and Thank you for your response.

Comment: PS. Pay attention - you use string literals in your procedure code in many places where the variables must be used logically (you use single quote char `'` instead of backtick).

Comment: @Akina, Update part is working very well, I just have to find part which rows didn't got updated and show that as output.

Comment: *Update part is working very well* I don't believe - due to the problem described above (wrong quoting).  For example, `AND DATE(date) BETWEEN '_startdate' AND '_enddate'` MUST produce "value truncated" warning message and give no output rows due to the truncated value gives FALSE condition value.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to check the existence of the rows before update. Just run the update and return the number of rows affected to PHP. If the return value was zero, you know the parameters passed do not have matching rows.

Also, if you use backticks to escape the variables, make sure you use backticks instead of single quotation marks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ABC(
_startdate DATE,
_enddate DATE,
_invc VARCHAR(100),
_amt VARCHAR(100),
_stones VARCHAR(100),
_tracking VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN

UPDATE quality_memo 
SET trackid = _tracking
WHERE invc = _invc AND value = _amt AND ttl_stones = _stones AND DATE(date) BETWEEN _startdate AND _enddate;

SELECT ROW_COUNT();

END
```

Comment: see don't want to find how mant number of row got affected or updated. AS I AM PASSING whole parameter of INVC, AMT and TTL_STONES and DATE, so i want which parameters didn't got satisfied IF EXISTS condition and print that only as OUTPUT. Thank you for your response

Comment: You do not need to use the number of rows that got affected other than when none of them was affected (procedure returns zero). Then you know that there are no matching rows with your criteria. So check the return value for the procedure for 0 and then do whatever you want to do.

Comment: I truely appreciate your effort, I am very new to all this, can you please show me an example. Please if possible, to make my concern clear.

Comment: Hi @slaakso, Any example will be okay and I'll refer that.

Comment: See the PHP documentation how to call your procedure and handle the result: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php